# Need "nameof" alternative in TypeScript, trying to initialise a variable to the nameof it's own variable name

Tags: typescript

Essentially I'm trying to find out how to create a readonly string that is equal to its own variable name in TypeScript. I can do this without issue in C# using the nameof function, but Typescript will not allow me to initialise a variable using itself.

In C# I have

```
public static readonly string Admin = nameof(Admin);
```

and that works fine, the value of Admin is "Admin".

I've tried the following in TypeScript

```
export class Resources {
    static nameof(variable: Object): string{
        const keys = Object.keys(variable);
        return keys[0];
    }

    static readonly Admin = Resources.nameof(Resources.Admin);
}
```

But that returns a "Property 'Admin' is used before its initialization." error.

Essentially I need variables that are equal to their variable names. I can't go into why I need them due to an NDA, but if anybody can give me some insights into a workaround, that would be wonderful.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want Resources.Admin to be 'Admin'?

Comment: Yes that's correct, and I don't want developers to manually type strings, so static readonly Admin = "Admin"; isn't going to work.

Comment: Variables or properties?  The former is probably hopeless, while the latter is probably achievable. As for "I can't go into why I need them due to an NDA", can you come up with an alternative, non-encumbered reason why someone would possibly need this?  It seems like a weird thing to need.  Anyway, assuming you want static class properties, does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wO8v7N) meet your needs?  If not, can you [edit] your question to show what use case isn't supported?

Comment: Well a good reason to use them would be to prevent developer typos. For instance if I had static readonly Admin = "Amdin" I might miss that, whereas if I were to try to have static readonly Admin = nameof(Amdin) then the compiler would yell at me. Unfortunately what you linked wouldn't work for my use case.